# GPG verify file and detached signature with given public key

Tags: signature, gnupg, pgp

I have a public key `pubkey.asc`.
Also I have a file `file.txt` and its detached signature `file.txt.asc`.

I want to check the following steps:

1. `file.txt.asc` is a signature for `file.txt`
2. `file.txt.asc` was created using secret key from a keyring with public key `pubkey.asc`

I can do the 1st step using `gpg --verify file.txt.asc file.txt`. This command outputs public key fingerprint which was used to create a signature:

```
gpg: Signature made <date and time>
gpg: using RSA key <fingerprint>
...
```

I can see `pubkey.asc` fingerprint just by running `gpg pubkey.asc`.

Can I use this information and just check if fingerprints are equal to perform 2nd step? If not, how can I verify a file signature with given public key?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011093) question about how to verify if signature matches public key, but it only works if key has extension `.gpg` which is not my case.

Comment: You might want to look at other questions like https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86721/can-i-specify-a-public-key-file-instead-of-recipient-when-encrypting-with-gpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenPGP key's fingerprint is a SHA1 hash of public key itself plus some additional data, and it uniquely identifies the key (excluding collision cases, which are not known yet for OpenPGP key fingerprints).

So, yeah, seeing 'good signature made by key [fingerprint]' is enough to rely on fact that signature is made by the aforementioned key.